# @Transactional AspectJ-like expressions

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-transactions, transactional

I'm moving my Spring application from old-style xml-based configuration to the annotation-based.
Currently I have all services defined in xml, and `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean` defined for each service.

```
    <bean id="dataServiceTarget" class="com.company.DataService">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataService" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="target" ref="dataServiceTarget"/>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
                <prop key="search*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I am about to annotate services with the `@Transactional` annotation.

From http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
  <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
  <tx:attributes>
    <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
    <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
    <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
    <tx:method name="*"/>
  </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>

  <!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
    of an operation defined by the FooService interface -->
  <aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation" expression="execution(* x.y.service.FooService.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation"/>
  </aop:config>
```

But I have to add `readonly=true` attribute to the `@Transactional` annotation every time I have method starting with `get`:

```
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public void getFoo() {
      return ...;  
  }
```

I have number of methods not starting with `get` and they shouldn't be read-only. So I can't place `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` on the class.

Possible solution is to divide classes to read-only and to read-write parts, but it's really hard with our code now. Another solution is to use example above.

Does Spring have ability to annotate all `get*` as read-only methods at once?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `readOnly=true` has a significant performance impact on your application? What do you use in your persistence layer?

Comment: Are you using `readOnly` to try to enforce correctness or for some other reason? Also, `@Transactional` is "inherited" along the call stack, so it's not necessary to annotate every getter with it, just your entry-point methods where transactions should start and stop.

Comment: @chrylis I'm using `readOnly` for proper transaction management due to  number of users using application at the same time. Also I'm using `readOnly` to enforce correctness=)

Comment: @JBNizet I don't exactly know the impact but I believe that application will run faster with `readOnly` because read operations are more often executed rather that write operations. But I can't make all methods read-only or not read-only on the class level as I described above.

Comment: If "you believe", but haven't measured anything yet, then I would leave them without the readOnly flag, and only add the flag when you have measured that a given read-only method is too slow and becomes fast enough with the readOnly flag set. Premature optimization is the root of all evils. And refactoring your app just to ease the setting of this flag without even knowing the impact of the flag is really evil.

Comment: @JBNizet I know about root of all evils. Project is about 7 years old, and it runs very slowly. I should optimize at least configuration now because even IntelliJ IDEA dies while opening it.

Comment: It's slow, but there is a very good chance that making the transactions read-only won't change anything to its slowness. And that won't make IntelliJ open the project facter either.

Comment: And have you tested that the XML-based configuration actually does what you think it does (turns an already-existing transaction read-only when you cross into a "read-only" method)?

Comment: @chrylis Do you ask about current xml or about example from springsource.org?